# ListBox with DoubleClick on Items using DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, listbox

I want to know if a double-clicking functionality for a `ListBox` can easily be build. I have a `ListBox` with a collection as `ItemSource`. The collection contains own data-types.

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Templates}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fileTemplate}">
```

I defined a `DataTemplate` for my `Items`, which consists of `StackPanel`s and `TextBlock`s.

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="fileTemplate">
     <Border>
         <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Filename}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         </StackPanel>
     </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I want to detect a double-click-event for the double-clicked list-item. Currently I tried with following, but it doesn't work because it doesn't return the Item bound to the `ListBox` but the `TextBlock`.

```
if (TemplateList.SelectedIndex != -1 && e.OriginalSource is Template)
{
    this.SelectedTemplate = e.OriginalSource as Template;
    this.Close();
}
```

What is a clean way to handle a double-click-event on an `item` in a `ListBox`, if the icons are not `ListBoxItems`, but own `DataTemplates`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been playing around with this and I think I've got there...

The good news is, that you can apply a style to your ListBoxItem *and* apply a DataTemplate - the one does not preclude the other...

In other words, you can have something like the following:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="fileTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:FileTemplate}">
...
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Templates}" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fileTemplate}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DoubleClickHandler" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

and then implement a handler in your Window, like

```
public void DoubleClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // item will be your dbl-clicked ListBoxItem
    var item = sender as ListBoxItem;

    // Handle the double-click - you can delegate this off to a 
    // Controller or ViewModel if you want to retain some separation
    // of concerns...
}
```